# How to solve MALA when the target density is known up to a constant?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings, gradient, langevin-diffusion

If you look at the wikipedia explanation of Metropolis adjusted Langevin Algorithm, the acceptance ratio is given by
[image]

The second equation involves taking the gradient of the log of $\pi(x)$. However, the whole reason for doing MCMC is that you do not know the exact formula for $\pi(x)$, only within a multiplicative constant. That's why take the ratio as shown in the 1st equation is ok.

So how do you implement MALA given this limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know $\pi(\cdot)$ up to a constant, a requirement for Metropolis-Hastings algorithms, the gradient
$$\nabla \log \pi(\cdot)$$is also independent from this constant.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Xi'an's answer, if $\pi(x) = c f(x)$, where $c$ is the unknown normalizing constant, then
\begin{align*}
\pi(x) & = c f(x)\\
\log \pi(x) & = \log(c) + \log f(x)\\
\Delta\log \pi(x) &= \Delta \log f(x).
\end{align*}

Thus, the normalizing constant is not required.